# Sorry, something went wrong The control type 'Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.TransformerConfigurationRecord' is not allowed on this page

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When i am trying to configure webpart filtering, i am getting the below error. Can any one give me some ideas how to resolve it.

Sorry, something went wrong
The control type

```
'Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.TransformerConfigurationRecord' is not allowed on this page. The type Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.TransformerConfigurationRecord, Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 3cc301a0-9639-d00d-a615-d017dedc2125 

Date and Time: 10/11/2021 13:26:05
```

Comment: Add the web part to other pages to compare the result, in addition, refer to following article to check if the solution works:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sharepoint-pages-do-not-render-when-using-unsafe-controls-0d94dc95-47dc-76d4-657c-76131faa66d7

Answer (score 0):

**Web.Config SafeControls**

```
  <SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.TransformerConfigurationRecord" TypeName="*" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.TransformerConfigurationRecord" TypeName="*" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards" TypeName="*" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards" TypeName="*" />
```